# Спарсить цену с сайта

Tags: powershell

Хочу cпарсить цену на товар, как можно это реализовать через powershell?
https://www.regard.ru/catalog/tovar348715.htm

$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://www.regard.ru/catalog/tovar348715.htm
$Response.Content

Необходимо получить строку

```
<span>10 750</span> руб.<br />
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не понял как это применить :D Ничего не выводит)